# Mock the Spring Environment Object In Junit with @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring

I have got a test like this

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class, TestConfig.class})
public class MyTest {
 ........
}
```

The AppConfig is the main config for my app, the TestConfig is the test config
which loads the test properties

```
  @Configuration
  @PropertySource("classpath:test_dev.properties")
    public class DevConfig {
  @Bean
  public DataSource getDataDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("driverclass"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("password"));
    return dataSource;
  }

}
```

problem is The test_dev.properties file has a encrypted password field
     driverclass = ojdbc:xxx

```
 url = xxxxxx
 username = abc
 password = #'"@~£$%
```

I need to use decryptor to decrypt it, then the decrypted password on the env object. thus env.get("password"), the real password will return

so my question is how can I mock the Environment object before the DataSource object gets crated.

Comment: And why wouldn't you just use mocked servlet context? To make things even more clear, using data source that connects to "live" database is not even a subject of `JUnit` tests.

Comment: 1) its not a web app thus no servlet 2) RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) is not exclusively for JUNIT isn't? integration test can use junit for sure. correct me if I am wrong. I have done loads integration tests in Junit. same as other people

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I wanted to mock the password filed on the datasource object

I first let the datasource bean initialize, then in my integration test autowired the mybatis Environment (don't be confused with springs environment).

from the env you can get the datasource.

from the @beforetest section, the trick is to use Reflectiontestutils.setfield to set the password field on the datasource

alternatively you could inject the entire datasource on the target environment
but I didn't try

the key motivation for using Spring is to easily inject mock objects.